Why is subjonctif imparfait used where passé simple is not?
I am reading L'Étranger and it does not use the passé simple. However, I've noticed it does use the subjonctif imparfait. See this excerpt:

J'ai trouvé qu'il était très commode que la justice se chargeât de ces détails.

If a book is deliberately using a more familiar spoken style with passé composé over passé simple, why not also use the normal subjunctive instead of subjonctif imparfait? Is it not similarly optional?

A side note that applies to spoken French, not to Camus who actually has a formal style as explained in the answers : In very rare cases, people enjoy being old-fashioned correct, and subjonctif imparfait used to be a rule. So they find it subversive or funny to use it. Passé simple over passé composé is not a rule, just an option, and it makes you sound like an actual book without the tongue-in-cheek aspect to it. So nobody speaks like that.

Je ne serai pas d'accord avec familiar spoken style. Certes Meursault est le narrateur qui nous livre ses pensées, mais du point de vue stylistique on est plus dans de l'expression écrite que dans de l'expression orale.  Les phrases sont simples et brèves, mais la langue en elle-même n'est pas familière.
On trouve du passé simple dans l'Étranger¹, même s'il est vrai que c'est le passé composé qui domine, le passé composé rend le personnage et le récit plus proches que le passé simple.

La phrase citée dans la question figure dans la deuxième partie du roman, quand Meursault réfléchit à son sort, et il y a plusieurs subjonctifs dans cette partie (alors qu'il me semble qu'il n'y en a pas dans la première). On peut très bien avoir un subjonctif imparfait dans la subordonnée avec une principale au passé composé (le passé composé est un temps du passé).

Par ailleurs  le livre a été écrit en 1940-41, si l'imparfait du subjonctif a presque entièrement disparu de la langue courante de nos jours, il n'était certes pas très courant en 1940, mais tout de même plus employé qu'aujourd'hui.  Dans l'Éducation nationale ce n'est qu'en 1976 que fut toléré l'emploi du présent du subjonctif à la place de l'imparfait quand la subordonnée est à un temps du passé. Voici un extrait de l'Arrêté du 28 décembre 1976, dans la section consacrée aux tolérances grammaticales ou orthographiques, et paru au JORF du 9 février 1977 :




Sur le site de l'Académie française : L’imparfait du subjonctif.


¹ À quatre reprises, je dis ça de mémoire, il faudrait que je le relise pour citer les phrases.
² Chacun réagira à sa façon, mais il faut quand même pouvoir prendre un peu de recul pour le lire. 

Je suis d'accord, ce n'est pas très familier. Pour renforce ce que dit None, L'Etranger date de 1942 (publication), et la maîtrise de la concordance des temps, ainsi que l'usage et les préférences de l'époque permettaient sans doute cette combinaison de façon plus courante qu'aujourd'hui.

@None I have kindly replaced your ridiculously large bullet points with normal sized ones, hopefully I did not misunderstand the intent of those giant black circles :)

@temporary_user_name Didn't realise they were so big... Thanks.

Anyway, I understand regarding "familiar spoken style" - I see that is not necessarily the connotation of using passé composé. So, between your and jlliagre's answers, should I understand that subjonctif imparfait is optional even for a past tense sentence, and that the choice to use it is stylistic? He could have used the normal subjunctive here?

It may be a stylistic choice, but I think it's also a tense coordination that we would not do automatically anymore, just because that subjonctif imparfait is falling out of usage.

@temporary_user_name It is optional nowadays, can be done but definitely a stylistic choice. In 1941 it had started to fall out of use but considered a grammar mistake in students' work if not used when main verb in a past tense. I doubt Camus was concerned by making grammar mistakes, moreover he loved using the subjonctif imparfait (cf. jlliagre's answer).

En complément de la réponse de None (+1), on peut lire dans l'incipit de La Chute ces réflexions qui peuvent je crois éclairer les lecteurs sur l'usage de l'imparfait du subjonctif par Camus (c'est moi qui grasseye) :

Notez bien que je ne le juge pas. J’estime sa méfiance fondée et la partagerais volontiers si, comme vous le voyez, ma nature communicative ne s’y opposait. Je suis bavard, hélas ! et me lie facilement. Bien que je sache garder les distances qui conviennent, toutes les occasions me sont bonnes. Quand je vivais en France, je ne pouvais rencontrer un homme d’esprit sans qu’aussitôt j’en fisse ma société. Ah ! je vois que vous bronchez sur cet imparfait du subjonctif. J’avoue ma faiblesse pour ce mode, et pour le beau langage, en général. Faiblesse que je me reproche, croyez-le. Je sais bien que le goût du linge fin ne suppose pas forcément qu’on ait les pieds sales. N’empêche. Le style, comme la popeline, dissimule trop souvent de l’eczéma. Je m’en console en me disant qu’après tout, ceux qui bafouillent, non plus, ne sont pas purs. Mais oui, reprenons du genièvre.

Voir aussi: Understanding the use of the imperfect subjunctive

Ah La Chute - je suis justement en train de le relire.
